# Always use wireless NIC for Internet access, if it's available

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, routing

I've got a Windows 7 machine with both a gigabit wired connection and a wireless adapter. Both interfaces have IP addresses on the same network (`192.168.0.0/24`).

I've got a single wireless router (`192.168.0.1`), which both the wired and wireless connect to. My fibre modem is connected to the WAN port of the router.

I *always* want to use the wired connection for local network access.

I always want to use the wireless connection for Internet access, if it's available, otherwise use the wired connection.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well you need to change the network adapter priority http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/

Comment: If you make this an answer, Cocowalla can  accept it and others can vote it up. :)

Comment: @AryaS. can you provide an answer with more information on how to use this for my specific case, where I want one interface to have priority for LAN, another for WAN?